# Create another col using value of other col

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in which I need to add another col based on the grouping logic.

Dataframe

```
 id|x_id|y_id|val_id|
  1| 2  |  3 |  4   |  
 10| 2  |  3 |  40  | 
  1| 12 | 13 | 14   |
```

I need to add other col `parent_id` which will be based on this rule:

*over `x_id` and `y_id` select the max value in col `val_id` and use its corresponding `id` value*

Final frame will look like this

```
 id|x_id|y_id|val_id| parent_id
 91| 2  |  3 |  4   |  10 (coming from row 2)
 10| 2  |  3 |  40  |  10 (coming from row 2)
  1| 12 | 13 | 14   |  14
```

I have tried using `withColumn`, but I can only set the row over that group that its value will be  parent.

**Explanation**: Here `parent_id` is 10 because its coming from col `id`. Row 2 was chosen because it has max value of `val_id` over group `x_id` and `y_id`

I am using scala

Comment: Hi your parent id logic is not clear. how is 10 coming in parent_id i feel 40 should be there isnt it ?

Comment: Have added more clarification @ram-ghadiyaram

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window` to split the ids and calculate the maximum over the window by sorting for each partition with respect to the `val_id`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy('x_id, 'y_id).orderBy('val_id.desc)

df.withColumn("parent_id", first('id).over(w))
  .show(false)
```

The result is:

```
+---+----+----+------+---------+
|id |x_id|y_id|val_id|parent_id|
+---+----+----+------+---------+
|10 |2   |3   |40    |10       |
|1  |2   |3   |4     |10       |
|1  |12  |13  |14    |1        |
+---+----+----+------+---------+
```